# Problema con subconsulta Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

realicé la siguiente consulta pero me devuelve el mensaje
**Property [toSql] does not exist on this collection instance**. Entiendo que el método toSql() no está en la instancia recuperada pero no puedo encontrar lo que necesito para disponer de este método.

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.7, también tengo importado el Facade DB

```
$query = ParteDiario::selectRaw('vehiculo_id, estadofin, max(created_at) as created_at')
            ->groupBy('vehiculo_id')
            ->having('estadofin', 'Detenido con fallas')
            ->get();

$q = DB::table(DB::raw("($query->toSql()) as q"))
            ->mergeBindings($query)
            ->selectRaw('count(q.vehiculo_id) as cantidad, DATE(q.created_at) as fecha')
            ->groupBy('fecha')
            ->get();
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

Si a la primera consulta le saco el método get(), me devuelve:

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$toSql**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce por colocarle a la variable $query un get() al final ya que este trae los valores y ya no tendría el metodo toSql() disponible, por lo tanto debes quitarle ese get() y tambien debes agregar llaves dentro de la funcion raw y la funcion getQuery() dentro de mergeBindings:

```
$query = ParteDiario::selectRaw('vehiculo_id, estadofin, max(created_at) as created_at')
            ->groupBy('vehiculo_id')
            ->having('estadofin', 'Detenido con fallas');//Removido ->get()

$q = DB::table(DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as q"))//Agregadas llaves
            ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())//Agregado getQuery()
            ->selectRaw('count(q.vehiculo_id) as cantidad, DATE(q.created_at) as fecha')
            ->groupBy('fecha')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Eso hice y me devuelve "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$toSql"

Comment: Intenta imprimir $query con dd($query->toSql) antes de la declaración de $q para ver que devuelve

Comment: Me devuelve: "select vehiculo_id, estadofin, max(created_at) as created_at from `partesdiarios` group by `vehiculo_id` having `estadofin` = ?"

Comment: Estoy usando "use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;"

Comment: Entonces esta funcionando correctamente el metodo toSql ya que lo que hace es devolver la representacion sql de tu consulta

Comment: Mejore la respuesta para corregir otros dos elementos erroneos, realiza las pruebas